# Call to a member function passes() on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I do have a feeling that I need to use Auth:: or something here to link to passes. Am I correct

**Issue Line**

```
    if($validator->passes())
```

`
    **getLoginCredentials**

```
protected function getLoginCredentials(Request $request)
  {
    $validator = $this->loginValidation($request);

    if($validator->passes())
    {
    return[
    'email'    => Request::input('email'),
    'password' => Request::input('password'),
    'type'     => 1  
    ];

    }else{
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors();
    }
  }
```

**loginValidation**

```
protected function loginValidation($request)
    {
        $rules = array(
          'email'      => 'required|email',
          'password'   => 'required',
    );
        $this->validate( $request , $rules);
    }
```

Comment: I bet `loginValidation` should return something different from `void`.

Comment: it should return true by my logic im just not sure how to implement

Comment: It can't return `true`, because is not an object as well. If you have this line `$validator->passes()`, then 100% `$validator` must be an object. If `loginValidation` doesn't return an object, your code will fail no matter what.

Comment: I think the issue is in `loginValidation`. Last line should be `return Validator::make($request, $rules);` instead of `$this->validate( $request , $rules);`

Comment: @Axalix Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, object given,

Comment: Sorry, `return Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);`

Comment: @Axalix Can you post as an answer so I can mark ticked when done :).  Thats fixed that issue now its given me an issue with the inputs in the getLoginCredentials function;  Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::input() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the actual problem is in the `loginValidation` method that should return an object. Please, see my code below. I've also changed `getLoginCredentials` a bit as `Request` shouldn't be called statically.

```
protected function getLoginCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->loginValidation($request);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        return [
            'email'    => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
            'type'     => 1  
        ];
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors();
    }
}
```

**loginValidation**

```
protected function loginValidation(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
      'email'      => 'required|email',
      'password'   => 'required',
    ];
    return Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
}
```